# Unable to fetch the index of second match

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get the index of my second match for the word skills. I want to match the keyword that is present alone and not in a sentence.

```
keyword = "skills"

def get_match_index(keyword, text):
    for sentence in text.split('\n'):
        if keyword == sentence.lower().strip():
            print(re.search(keyword,text))
```

This will return the index of the first search.
Here is the text.

```
Assessed and changed skills required to take company to next level in the IT, HR, Accounting.
-
College Station

Skills
```

I want to match the second instance of keyword here - "Skills", a heading, not a sentence.

Comment: Your condition only matches the line that consists of `Skills`. I fail to see what's going wrong. Can you provide a clearer notion of your expected output and what you get instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "not in a sentence"?

Comment: Do you mean [**`(?i)^skills$`**](https://regex101.com/r/VgEzin/1/) with the `multiline` and case insensitive modifier ?

Comment: @liliscent By "not in a sentence", I meant I want to find matched headings and not sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `search` you can use [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
keyword = "skills"

def get_match_index(keyword, text):
    for sentence in text.split('\n'):
        if keyword == sentence.lower().strip():
            print(re.findall(keyword,text))
```

Docs says:

> re.search(pattern, string, flags=0) re.searScan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance.

and

> re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
>       Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings.

Comment: While findall can find all matches, how can I get the index of the second match?

Comment: hm, `finditer` would be a better choice. It returns iterator with `MatchObjects`. You can get positions from `MatchObjects`

Comment: got the result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solving your problem in another way, you could look for an uppercase `Skill` instead:

```
def get_match_index(keyword, text):
    start_match = text.index(keyword)
    end_match = start_match + len(text)
    return start_match, end_match
```

, which would in this form return the same as a `span()` call from this regex:

```
def get_match_index(keyword, text):
    pattern = re.compile(f"(?<=\n){keyword}")
    return pattern.search(text.lower()).span()
```

Comment: Thanks @Arne for looking into this problem. I am not looking for line number but more exact location of the match. re.search(keyword,text).span() gives the exact index, but it only returns the first match. Which is not the correct answer.

Comment: @joe I changed some parts, is this closer to what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the desired result. Thanks @mrzasa for suggesting the finditer method. Thanks @Arne, you result matches for uppercase.

```
pattern = r'(?i)^skills$'
regex = re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)

match_tup = [match.span() for match in re.finditer(r'(?i)^skills$',text,re.MULTILINE)]
print(match_tup)
```